# Key Shortcut to Search

Tags: search, gvim

**Which key(s) are the shortcut for searching the file for the word the cursor was on?**

I was distracted and didn't realize that I was still in gvim when I started typing something for the terminal.  After a few keystrokes, I noticed that a lot of highlighting had shown up in gvim.  It appeared to have searched for the word that my cursor had been on.  I know I didn't have this word copied, hadn't been in search mode, and I'm pretty sure I didn't hit the '/' key while typing.  That being said, I tried retyping what I had done before, but didn't get the same result.  I may have hit the wrong key(s) when I was typing my terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both in vim and gvim:

- `*` is to search current word forward
- `#` backward

Comment: That's probably not what I did, but it's better than what I think happened.  Can that be expanded to things like "Search string from here to end of line"?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant, I just accidentally did it while trying to do something else.

**SHIFT + Left Mouse will search the file for the word that you click.**

I must've bumped my laptop's touchpad while typing 'G'

Comment: Experimenting is fine. There's also `:help user-manual` for when you grow tired of learning features by accident.